# Getting a list of strings by splitting a string by a specific tag

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I would like to split a string into a list or array by a specific tag.

```
<START><A>message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF><AEOF><A>message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF><AEOF><END>
```

I want to split the above example into two items, the items being the strings between the `<A>` and `<AEOF>` tags

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This looks vaguely like XML. Is it GML or something else?

Comment: That's terribly non-useful. I want to know if it is a known format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest simple regex for this. 
Take a look at this example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

...

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<A>(.*?)<B><BEOF>(.*?)<AEOF>");
string myString = @"<START><A>message<B><BEOF>UnknownLengthOfText<AEOF><A>message<B><BEOF>some other line of text<AEOF><END>";
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(myString);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].ToString(), m.Groups[2].ToString());
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since string is in one line, regex should be "lazy", marked with lazy quantifier `?`. Also, I changed regex so that it uses sTrenat's suggestion to automatically parse message and title also.

So, instead of

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<A>(.*)<AEOF>");
```

I used

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<A>(.*?)<B><BEOF>(.*?)<AEOF>");
```

Notice additional `?` which marks lazy quantifier, to stop when it finds first match between tags (without `?` whole strign will be captured and not `n` messages between tags)

Comment: Actually, you could extract 2 messeges with `Regex regex = new Regex("<A>(.*)<B><BEOF>(.*)<AEOF>");`  
Then Title is: `m.Groups[1]`, and Content is `m.Groups[2]`

Comment: @sTrenat nice addition. It's unclear know what OP actually needs, but your comment could be improvement and useful. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @sTrenat for the great addition

Comment: @Nino, it seems that if 'myString' is a single line like this " <START> <A>message<B><BEOF>UnknownLengthOfText<AEOF> <A>message<B><BEOF>some other line of text<AEOF> <END>", then it does not work, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with something like this:

```
string test = @"<START>
                   <A>message<B><BEOF>UnknownLengthOfText<AEOF>
                   <A>message<B><BEOF>UnknownLengthOfText<AEOF>
                <END>";

//for this test this will give u an array containing 3 items...
string[] tmp1 = test.Split("<AEOF>");

//here u will store your results in
List<string> results = new List<string>();

//for every single one of those 3 items:
foreach(string item in tmp1)
{
     //this will only be true for the first and second item
     if(item.Contains("<A>"))
     {
           string[] tmp2 = item.Split("<A>");

           //As the string you are looking for is always BEHIND the <A> you 
           //store the item[1], (the item[0] would be in front)

           results.Add(tmp2[1]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the String.Split you can use the Regex.Split as below

```
        var stringToSplit = @"<START>
                                <A>message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF><AEOF>
                                <A>message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF><AEOF>
                            <END>";

        var regex = "<A>(.*)<AEOF>";
        var splitStrings = Regex.Split(stringToSplit, regex);
```

splitStrings will contain 4 elements

```
splitString[0] = "<START>"
splitString[1] = "message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF>"
splitString[2] = "message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF>"
splitString[3] = "<END>"
```

Playing with the regex could give you only the strings between  and

Answer (score 0):

All answer so far are regex based. Here is an alternative without:

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BLfoFh)

```
    var input = @"
<START>
    <A>message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF><AEOF>
    <A>message<B>UnknownLengthOfText<BEOF><AEOF>
<END>";
    var start = "<A>";
    var end = "<AEOF>";
    foreach (var item in ExtractEach(input, start, end))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractEach(string input, string start, string end)
{
    foreach (var line in input
             .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
             .Where(x=> x.IndexOf(start) > 0 && x.IndexOf(start) < x.IndexOf(end)))
    {
        yield return Extract(line, start, end);
    }
}


public static string Extract(string input, string start, string end)
{
    int startPosition = input.LastIndexOf(start) + start.Length;
    int length = input.IndexOf(end) - startPosition;
    var substring = input.Substring(startPosition, length);
    return substring;
}
```